# Worklight 5.0.6 Dojo code migration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have develop a simple application on worklight 5.0.5 and it's working fine but after updating to version 5.0.6 I am facing some issues. When I launch the application dojo's libs are not integrated with my application. 
Can any one help me regarding this? Thanks,

It give me the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function klass() {
this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
} has no method 'setConnected'
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Worklight 5.0.6 InfoCenter for details on code migration when you upgrade: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devenv/r_migrating_to_a_newer_version_of_ibm_worklight.html

> If you created your current project with an earlier version of IBM
>   Worklight Studio, consider migrating the code to the new Dojo module
>   loading technique in addition to upgrading the Dojo toolkit. It
>   ensures that the code performs more reliably and that the page
>   continues to work when it makes further changes in RPE.
>
> Specifically, the Dojo layers are no longer loaded from HTML elements,
>   but instead they are loaded by require() calls inside the
>   wlCommonInit() method. The individual modules are loaded from
>   require() calls inside the dojoInit() method.

Here is the link to the specific Dojo 1.8.3 code changes: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devenv/t_dojo_183_code_migration.html

Comment: Thanks for your response Handly, I follow this and resolve all the issue that I faced. But I have only one issue left when my application is launched then following error is occurred 

POST http://localhost:8080/apps/services/api/JCC/common/init 401 (Unauthorized) base.js:883
window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.request base.js:883
window.WLJSX.Ajax.Request.WLJSX.Class.create.initialize base.js:844
klass base.js:325
window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.sendRequest worklight.js:1313
window.WLJSX.Ajax.WLRequest.WLJSX.Class.create.initialize worklight.js:1214
klass base.js:325